# Why AVSpeechUtterance.language cheating me?

Tags: ios, swift, locale, text-to-speech

I am developing an app that has a text to speech feature. I also let the user to choose want language they want by changing the `voice` of the `AVSpeechUtterance`. The language is either American English (`en-us`) or British English (`en-uk`).

I tested the app by synthesising

```
Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers
```

In the speech, I could clearly hear the -er in "answer". So it was American English. But I actually selected British English!

Then I selected American English and the same, exact voice is produced!

I thought this was because I didn't actually set the `voice` property to `en-uk`. So I added some breakpoints and check. It turns out that I *did* set it to `en-uk`!

Why is this? Is British English just not available? Or did I entered the locale wrongly? `en-uk` is not the right one?

Comment: Try to use `en-gb`. According to ISO 3166-1, "UK" is deprecated country code.

Comment: @Kae10 Thank you! Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure! Thanks to check my comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `en-gb`. According to ISO 3166-1, "UK" is deprecated country code.